# My Laravel can not receive the information into a package in format json

Tags: php, json, ajax, laravel, modal-dialog

I have form, there are many field. i want Laravel receive the information into a package in format json, But my code its not work, i think my "modalScipt.js" its wrong. please fix it :

my controller :

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        if($request->ajax()){
            return response()->json([
               "pesan" => $request->all()
            ]);
        }
    }
```

My modalScript.js

```
$("#createLoker").click(function(){
    var datas = $("#judul","#namaPt","#deadline","#deskripsi","#profilePt").val();
    var route = "http://localhost:8000/lowongan";
    var token = $("#token").val();

    $.ajax({
        url:route,
        headers : {'X-CSRF-TOKEN':token},
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data:{judul:datas,
              namaPt:datas,
              deadline:datas,
              deskripsi:datas,
              profilePt:datas
        }
    });
});
```

thi is my index.blade

```
{!!Form::open()!!}
 <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}" id="token">
  <form class="form-horizontal">
    {!!Form::text('judul',null,['id'=>'judul','class'=>'form-control','placeholder'=>'Judul Lowongan'])!!} </div>
    {!!Form::text('namaPt',null,['id'=>'namaPt','class'=>'form-control','placeholder'=>'Nama PT'])!!}
..........
{!!Form::close()!!}
{!!Html::script('js/scriptModal.js')!!}
```

This is output When i inspect element.
[image: my blank data]

Comment: what is send to the server? please show the headers of your ajax call.

Comment: i want send my data from datas variable `var datas = $("#judul","#namaPt","#deadline","#deskripsi","#profilePt").val();` , I get my var datas from data in the <form> in index.blade @mimo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var datas = $("#judul","#namaPt","#deadline","#deskripsi","#profilePt").val();
```

will return undefined because jquery can't handle it.

```
var route = "http://localhost:8000/lowongan";
var token = $("#token").val();

$.ajax({
    url:route,
    headers : {'X-CSRF-TOKEN':token},
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    data:{judul: $("#judul").val(),
          namaPt: $("#namaPt").val(),
          deadline: $("#deadline").val(),
          deskripsi: $("#deskripsi").val(),
          profilePt: $("#profilePt").val();
    }
});
```

When all your datas are in the form you can use

```
$('form').serializeArray();
```

that will return an array with all inputs.